# why ffmpeg only combines first 390 images when combining very large amount ( about 9k) images into video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a VCD, and I split it into nearly 10,000 images, named like:

```
$ ls tmp_enlarged_image_folder

vcd3_00000001.png
vcd3_00000002.png
vcd3_00000003.png
vcd3_00000004.png
...
vcd3_00089998.png
vcd3_00089999.png
vcd3_00090000.png
```

and the following command doen't work for me:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel trace -f image2 -r 25 -pattern_type sequence -i 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-%08d.png' -vcodec libx264 test.mp4
```

and the detailed log shows as below:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'trace'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'image2'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '25'.
Reading option '-pattern_type' ... matched as AVOption 'pattern_type' with argument 'sequence'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-%08d.png'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option 'test.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument trace.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-%08d.png.
Applying option f (force format) with argument image2.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 25.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-%08d.png.
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000001.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8b9a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d898e0] Statistics: 60162 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000002.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8be80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8c0a0] Statistics: 58890 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000003.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8be80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d92420] Statistics: 59492 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000004.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d92860] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d92900] Statistics: 59467 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000005.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d92860] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d92d00] Statistics: 98769 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000006.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d92fa0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d93280] Statistics: 100294 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000007.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d93140] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d934a0] Statistics: 99530 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000008.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d930a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d936c0] Statistics: 141874 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000009.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8c420] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d93840] Statistics: 146849 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000010.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d93840] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8c640] Statistics: 142622 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000011.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8c7c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8c860] Statistics: 161083 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000012.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8c7c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8c9a0] Statistics: 168437 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000013.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8c7c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8ca20] Statistics: 160565 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000014.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8ca20] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8cd40] Statistics: 99356 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000015.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8cc20] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8cd40] Statistics: 101508 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000016.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8cc20] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8cd40] Statistics: 99081 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000017.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8cf20] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8d040] Statistics: 150550 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000018.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8d040] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8d4c0] Statistics: 156717 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000019.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8d700] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8d7a0] Statistics: 151933 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000020.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8d7c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8da80] Statistics: 167036 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000021.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8d860] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8da00] Statistics: 177571 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000022.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da25a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da2640] Statistics: 169959 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000023.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da25a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da28a0] Statistics: 176603 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000024.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da2580] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da2620] Statistics: 190698 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000025.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da29a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da2620] Statistics: 175826 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000026.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da2dc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da2620] Statistics: 148180 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000027.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da2620] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3060] Statistics: 149163 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000028.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da2620] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3080] Statistics: 145310 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000029.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3080] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da2f20] Statistics: 169361 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000030.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da34a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3540] Statistics: 177868 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000031.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da34a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3680] Statistics: 170215 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000032.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3680] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3540] Statistics: 179543 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000033.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da38a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3a80] Statistics: 191447 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000034.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3cc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3e60] Statistics: 178243 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000035.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3e60] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3f00] Statistics: 181307 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000036.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3e60] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da4160] Statistics: 199093 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Probe buffer size limit of 5000000 bytes reached
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] stream 0: start_time: 0.000 duration: 27.520
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] format: start_time: 0.000 duration: 27.520 bitrate=0 kb/s
Input #0, image2, from 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-%08d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:27.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 36, 1/25: Video: png, 1 reference frame, rgb24(pc), 704x576, 0/1, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url test.mp4.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument libx264.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: test.mp4.
File 'test.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[file @ 0x560f96d8b800] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 4 times
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] Setting 'video_size' to value '704x576'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/25'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '0/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x560f96dbb5e0] w:704 h:576 pixfmt:rgb24 tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0x560f96db9cc0] compat: called with args=[yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21]
[format @ 0x560f96db9cc0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x560f96dbdd00] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x560f96dbdd00] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0x560f96db9cc0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x560f96d8bc60] query_formats: 4 queried, 2 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x560f96dbdd00] picking yuv444p out of 8 ref:rgb24 alpha:0
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x560f96dbdd00] w:704 h:576 fmt:rgb24 sar:0/1 -> w:704 h:576 fmt:yuv444p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] using mv_range_thread = 40
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/12800: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 704x576, 0/1, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 31 times
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000037.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3e40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da34a0] Statistics: 181873 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000038.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3e40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da34a0] Statistics: 134566 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000039.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d92860] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d8dae0] Statistics: 137871 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000040.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8dae0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d92860] Statistics: 136224 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000041.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8db00] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3020] Statistics: 168070 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000042.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3d40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3020] Statistics: 176575 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000043.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3d40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3040] Statistics: 168955 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000044.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da2dc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da2e60] Statistics: 176179 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000045.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3020] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da30c0] Statistics: 189823 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000046.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da39c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3680] Statistics: 174410 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000047.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d93920] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f98047100] Statistics: 184740 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000048.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d8db60] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f98047100] Statistics: 198932 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000049.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f9807d700] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f98047100] Statistics: 184479 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000050.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f9807d700] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f9811c3c0] Statistics: 141160 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000051.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d928e0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3660] Statistics: 145336 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000052.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f9807d700] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d937a0] Statistics: 143174 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000053.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3cc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d937c0] Statistics: 163488 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000054.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da37e0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f980eb240] Statistics: 171633 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream) 0x    
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000055.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3cc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d92860] Statistics: 164825 bytes read, 0 seeks
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame=   0 QP=13.88 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:1584 P:0    SKIP:0    size=1578 bytes
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000056.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da3ce0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d937c0] Statistics: 175255 bytes read, 0 seeks
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame=   1 QP=16.06 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8   I:183  P:97   SKIP:1304 size=659 bytes
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000057.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da37e0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3660] Statistics: 185462 bytes read, 0 seeks
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame=   2 QP=14.21 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:4   I:0    P:207  SKIP:1377 size=220 bytes
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000058.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d937a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d92f20] Statistics: 175635 bytes read, 0 seeks
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame=   3 QP=19.00 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:2   I:2    P:38   SKIP:1544 size=65 bytes
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000059.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96d937a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96da3660] Statistics: 183556 bytes read, 0 seeks
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame=   4 QP=19.00 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:6   I:1    P:140  SKIP:1443 size=109 bytes
[image2 @ 0x560f96d859e0] Opening 'tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-00000060.png' for reading
[file @ 0x560f96da28e0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d93020] Statistics: 200369 bytes read, 0 seeks
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] scene cut at 13 Icost:32063 Pcost:31308 ratio:0.0235 bias:0.0520 gop:13 (imb:1301 pmb:127)

....

[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 381 QP=23.59 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:368 I:1    P:261  SKIP:1322 size=237 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 382 QP=20.58 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:378 I:374  P:512  SKIP:698  size=1966 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 383 QP=20.62 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:374 I:28   P:555  SKIP:1001 size=1061 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 384 QP=19.35 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:372 I:4    P:349  SKIP:1231 size=325 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 385 QP=22.98 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:376 I:3    P:348  SKIP:1233 size=337 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 386 QP=22.53 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:386 I:139  P:398  SKIP:1047 size=899 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 387 QP=20.57 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:382 I:5    P:373  SKIP:1206 size=522 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 388 QP=21.35 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:380 I:2    P:188  SKIP:1394 size=175 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame= 389 QP=24.00 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:384 I:4    P:335  SKIP:1245 size=309 bytes
frame=  390 fps= 88 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1179kB time=00:00:15.48 bitrate= 623.8kbits/s speed=3.48x    
video:1173kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.458639%
Input file #0 (tmp_enlarged_image_folder/vcd3-%08d.png):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 390 packets read (133376897 bytes); 390 frames decoded; 
  Total: 390 packets (133376897 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 390 frames encoded; 390 packets muxed (1201598 bytes); 
  Total: 390 packets (1201598 bytes) muxed
390 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x560f96d91840] Statistics: 2 seeks, 8 writeouts
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame I:16    Avg QP:15.26  size:  5467
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame P:105   Avg QP:20.74  size:  6272
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] frame B:269   Avg QP:24.76  size:  1691
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] consecutive B-frames:  5.1%  8.2%  1.5% 85.1%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] mb I  I16..4: 80.4%  0.0% 19.6%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] mb P  I16..4: 12.5%  0.0%  4.7%  P16..4: 28.6%  8.5%  4.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:41.4%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.6%  0.0%  0.4%  B16..8: 32.3%  2.1%  0.3%  direct: 2.3%  skip:61.8%  L0:44.0% L1:51.7% BI: 4.3%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] coded y,u,v intra: 22.2% 7.4% 6.0% inter: 8.1% 1.6% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 47% 24% 10% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 18% 26%  5%  5%  6%  4%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:7.6% UV:6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] ref P L0: 52.1% 11.4% 25.3% 11.1%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] ref B L0: 80.7% 15.2%  4.1%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] ref B L1: 91.6%  8.4%
[libx264 @ 0x560f96d8e8c0] kb/s:615.85
```

Answer (score 1):

OK， my mistake.

I list the files in the folder, and found the files format are not the same as I expected:

```
....
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  371245 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000388.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  376347 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000389.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  379002 Jul  2 17:33 vcd3_00000390.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  379002 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000390.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  377153 Jul  2 17:33 vcd3_00000391.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei       0 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000391.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  376372 Jul  2 17:34 vcd3_00000392.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei       0 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000392.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  381799 Jul  2 17:34 vcd3_00000393.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei       0 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000393.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  378492 Jul  2 17:34 vcd3_00000394.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei       0 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000394.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  381229 Jul  2 17:34 vcd3_00000395.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei       0 Jul  2 14:57 vcd3-00000395.png*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 siwei siwei  383011 Jul  2 17:34 vcd3_00000396.png*
....
```

Comment: I was just about to say, I re-created this and the only way I could get it to fail was to damage a file in the sequence.  i.e. `rm vcd3_00000391.png`

Comment: ^_^  thank you so much ! you are tell the truth!